# DSE 6 create solr cores through http

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I'm attempting to use the following http request to create a solr core:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=service_name.resource&generateResources=false
```

The response i'm getting is

```
[create] action is not supported!
```

I'm using the version of dse 6 available direct from the site. 5.0 and 5.1 work fine, but 6 returns the above error, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the HTTP APIs supported in the 5.x versions are removed in the DSE 6, including the core administration.

You need to use [CQL syntax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateSearchIndex.html) (recommended), or `dsetool` (older, less recommended) to manipulate the DSE Search cores.

P.S. From my experience, using the CQL it is easier, and doesn't require to have access to Solr UI, or command line.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a reread of the [release notes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/releaseNotes/RNdse.html) and i still don't see this change? Was it missed or do i need new glasses? :)

Comment: It was DSP-13530, but somehow the title of another JIRA was published under it - I'll ask to fix it